# Animating navigation bar elements on scroll in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am trying to create a similar animation to the Apple TV app - specifically [this animation](https://youtube.com/shorts/o7xmWlXLogA)

Here are just some screenshots of the different states of this transition

1 - No title, a back button, add button and share button in white color

[image]

2 - After a certain point of scrolling, we can see the color of the buttons in the navigation bar changing

[image]

3 - After scrolling some more, a title appears in the nav bar, the buttons change color and the nav bar itself becomes translucent

[image]

How can such an animation be achieved in SwiftUI ?

The only thing I can think of at the moment would be to use a UIScrollView within swiftUI so that we can make use of the delegates it offers. However, even beyond this, I am uncertain of how to achieve such animations in UIKit as well.

However, how can we apply these different navigation bar animations in SwiftUI of the:

- Navigation Style from opaque to translucent
- The color of the different buttons
- The navigation bar title

Comment: You might be able to use some of the techniques shown in the answer to [Change NavigationStack title font, tint, and background in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77820285/20386264)

Comment: You can probably do it easily with `ScrollView` with `scrollTransition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar thing trying to replicate the Spotify album view where I have a Sticky Header that fades out after the user scrolls up. I have modified it a bit to give you an idea on how to reach the translucency effect. You can use the Material.ultraThinMaterial or similar materials from that struct. Here' some documentation from Apple:

```
extension ShapeStyle where Self == Material {

    /// A material that's somewhat translucent.
    public static var regularMaterial: Material { get }

    /// A material that's more opaque than translucent.
    public static var thickMaterial: Material { get }

    /// A material that's more translucent than opaque.
    public static var thinMaterial: Material { get }

    /// A mostly translucent material.
    public static var ultraThinMaterial: Material { get }

    /// A mostly opaque material.
    public static var ultraThickMaterial: Material { get }
}
```

And now to the fun part, the stikcy header. My code will work on iOS 16+. I also added some comment to indicate you were to modify header colors. As you can see the back arrow becomes blue after a certain point. This was just to give you an idea. Code:

```
struct Home: View {
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var safeArea: EdgeInsets
    var size: CGSize
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            
            VStack {
                /// Album Pic
                ArtWork()
                
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    /// Since we ignored top edge
                    let minY = proxy.frame(in: .named("SCROLL")).minY - safeArea.top
                    
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Text("SHUFFLE PLAY")
                            .font(.callout)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 45)
                            .padding(.vertical, 12)
                            .background {
                                Capsule()
                                    .fill(.spotifyGreen.gradient)
                            }
                    }) //: BUTTON SHUFFLE PLAY
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .offset(y: minY < 50 ? -(minY - 50) : 0)
                } //: GEOMETRY
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.top, -34)
                .zIndex(1)
                
                VStack {
                    
                    Text("Popular")
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    
                    /// Album View
                    AlbumView()
                    
                } //: VSTACK
                .padding(.top, 10)
                .zIndex(0)
                
            } //: VSTACK
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                HeaderView()
            }
            
        } //: SCROLL
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .coordinateSpace(name: "SCROLL")
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Views
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func ArtWork() -> some View {
        let randomListens = Int.random(in: 5_000_000...30_000_000)
        let height = size.height * 0.45
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size
            let minY = proxy.frame(in: .named("SCROLL")).minY
            let progress = minY / (height * (minY > 0 ? 0.5 : 0.8))
            
            Image(.myloxyloto)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height + (minY > 0 ? minY : 0))
                .clipped()
                .overlay {
                    ZStack {
                        
                        /// Gradient Overlay
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(
                                .linearGradient(colors: [
                                    .black.opacity(0 - progress),
                                    .black.opacity(0.1 - progress),
                                    .black.opacity(0.3 - progress),
                                    .black.opacity(0.5 - progress),
                                    .black.opacity(0.8 - progress),
                                    .black.opacity(1),
                                ], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                            )
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            
                            
                            Text("Mylo Xyloto")
                                .font(.system(size: 45))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            
                            Text("Coldplay")
                                .font(.callout.bold())
                                .padding(.top, 15)
                            
                            Text("\(randomListens) Monthly Listners")
                                .font(.caption)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                                //.padding(.top, 15)
                                
                            
                        } //: VSTACK
                        .opacity(1 + (progress > 0 ? -progress : progress))
                        /// Moving with ScrollView
                        .padding(.bottom, 55)
                        .offset(y: minY < 0 ? minY : 0)
                        
                    } //: ZSTACK
                } //: Gradient Overlay
                .offset(y: -minY)
            
        } //: GEOMETRY
        .frame(height: height + safeArea.top)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func AlbumView() -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 25) {
            ForEach(songs.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                HStack(spacing: 25) {
                    
                    let randomListens = Int.random(in: 200_000...2_000_000)
                    
                    Text("\(index + 1)")
                        .font(.callout)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                        Text(songs[index].songName)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        
                        Text("\(randomListens)")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                        
                    } //: VSTACK
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                }
            } //: LOOP Songs
        } //: VSTACK
        .padding(15)
    }
    
    /// Header View
    @ViewBuilder
    func HeaderView() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let minY = proxy.frame(in: .named("SCROLL")).minY
            let height = size.height * 0.45
            let progress = minY / (height * (minY > 0 ? 0.5 : 0.8))
            let titleProgress = minY / height
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        .font(.title3)
                        /// You could use titleprogress to apply different styles based on the scroll position
                        .foregroundStyle(-titleProgress < 0.75 ? .white : .blue)
                }) //: Back Button
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("FOLLOWING")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        .padding(.vertical, 6)
                        .overlay(
                            Capsule()
                                .stroke(style: .init(lineWidth: 1))
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        )
                }) //: Follow Button
                .opacity(1 + progress)
                
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                }) //: Back Button
            } //: HSTACK
            .overlay {
                Text("Coldplay")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    /// Choose where to display the title
                    .offset(y: -titleProgress > 0.75 ? 0 : 45)
                    .clipped()
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25),
                               value: -titleProgress > 0.75 ? 0 : 45)
            }
            .padding(.top, safeArea.top + 10)
            .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 15)
            .background {
                //Color.black
                Rectangle()
                    /// Apply Material effects here for translucency or similar stuff
                    .fill(Material.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .opacity(-progress > 1 ? 1 : 0)
            }
            .offset(y: -minY)
            
        } //: GEOMETRY
        .frame(height: 35)
    }
    
}
```

Apart from missing images and some color it should work out of the box.
You can use it like this:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    let safeArea = proxy.safeAreaInsets
    let size = proxy.size
    Home(safeArea: safeArea, size: size)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: [.top])
}
.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
```

Result:

[image: Sticky Header with material effect]

Let me know if this can work for you!

Comment: Thanks for putting such a detailed explanation together. Let me give this a go later today and I'll let you know / mark it as answer.

Comment: Take your time to try it :) and let me know if you have any trouble or doubt.

Comment: I was just able to try it. Overall, in terms of UX, it looks great. I did notice though, it seems you are building your own navigation bar so it doesn't really use the navigation stack provided by SwiftUI ? My only worry is that what happens if we push this view onto a view stack, we will need to hide the nav bar that comes with the navigation stack right ? And then I wonder if we will also lose the swipe to go back gesture ? Finally, I couldn't understand the logic around getting the shuffle button to stick at the top, how did you manage to do that ?

Comment: You are right, when you push a new view using the NavigationStack and you also hide the default navbar you lose the swipe to delete but, it turns out you can overcome that issue by using my custom FullSwipeNavigationStack to always allow the swiping on any page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77865035/swiftui-page-switch-stuck-when-navigationbar-changed-in-ios17-2/77866820#77866820. There's an intersting discussion about it here also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77939564/swift-ui-execute-function-programmatically-when-view-disappears/77960488#77960488

Comment: As for the shuffle button, it sticks on top because of this line: .offset(y: minY < 50 ? -(minY - 50) : 0) and because of the minY we subtract the safeArea.top. If you comment either of those two the Shuffle button will go away when swiping up. Let me know if you have more questions, and your thoughts about the FullSwipeNavigationStack.