# Can’t make a button tappable parallel to navigationTitle

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-button, swiftui-navigation

[image]

The button is not tappable as I move it to the extended line of the title. If I move it to somewhere else, it works but I want to place it on the line of Title.

But whenever I do it, it does not tappable feels like its tappable area conflicts or masked by something.  Is it SwiftUI limitation? If so, how this Health app made it work ? Don't say that it's because they're Apple :(  Any help is appreciated in this matter!

Tried Moving the button to different places bottom of the navigationTitle line and it worked.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            print("tapped")
                        }) {
                            Text("XX") 
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                .background(Circle().strokeBorder(.blue, lineWidth: 4))
                                .background(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.white))
                                .padding()
                        }
                        .padding(.top, -80)
                        .background(
                            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView(), isActive: $isPresented) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
                Text("Main Body")
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .large)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The negative padding looks like it could be the root of the problem. Try to fix the layout so that it works without negative padding or offset.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but can you share your idea more clearly? In which other way to bring the button to the desired place and enable the tap area?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to be permanently visible then you could make it a `ToolbarItem` with placement `.topBarTrailing`. However, it seems you want it to be adjacent to the navigation title and to scroll out of view with the title.

One solution would be to replace the native navigation title with your own header. This can contain any content you like and it can also be styled any way you like. The answer to [Change NavigationStack title font, tint, and background in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77820285/20386264) shows how it can be done (it was my answer).

I'm not quite clear why your button has a `NavigationLink` in the background. A `NavigationLink` is also a button. I would suggest using one or the other, but not both.

So here is how your example can be updated to use a self-styled header. An outer `GeometryReader` is not needed in your case, because the coordinate space of the `ScrollView` can be referenced directly (it was needed for the other answer I referenced above, because the main content there was a `List`):

```swift
struct TestView: View {

    @State var isPresented = false
    @State private var showingScrolledTitle = false

    private var scrollDetector: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in

            // pre iOS 17: the coordinate space of the ScrollView needs to be named
            let maxY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView).maxY
            let isUnderToolbar = maxY < (proxy.size.height / 2)
            Color.clear
                // pre iOS 17: .onChange(of: isUnderToolbar) { newVal in
                .onChange(of: isUnderToolbar) { _, newVal in
                    showingScrolledTitle = newVal
                }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.leading)
                    Spacer()

                    Button {
                        print("tapped")
                    } label: {
                        Text("XX")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                            .background(Circle().strokeBorder(.blue, lineWidth: 4))
                            .background(Circle().foregroundColor(Color.white))
                            .padding()
                    }
//                    .background(
//                        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView(), isActive: $isPresented) {
//                            EmptyView()
//                        }
//                    )
                }
                .background { scrollDetector }

                Text("Main Body")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .opacity(showingScrolledTitle ? 1 : 0)
                        .animation(.easeInOut, value: showingScrolledTitle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks so much. So far this is the closest answer but still we will lose the stock animation (navigationTitle becomes back button in next view) when you navigate to different view which is also there in Health App.

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback. The stock animation works for the (smaller) toolbar title, but as you say, it is missing for the big title (if the big title is actually visible, ie before scrolling). You actually see the animation for the smaller title even when the big title is showing. Beyond that, I think it will be very difficult to get the big title to shrink into position, not least, because the whole view is being replaced while it is happening. I guess it's the compromise that comes with a custom header.